# Empty PDF in IEEE Communication Template

Tags: math-mode, equations, ieeetran, ieee-style

I am stuck in a very weird problem. When I just write a line $I_E(0)$ in the attached IEEE template, I get an empty PDF. If I remove this line, I get perfect compile and PDF output.

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% optional T1 font encoding
\usepackage{amsmath}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\begin{document}
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for\\ IEEE Communications Society Journals}
\author{Michael~Shell,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE,}
        John~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Fellow,~OSA,}
        and~Jane~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Life~Fellow,~IEEE}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{M. Shell was with the Department
of Electrical and Computer Engineering, Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta,
GA, 30332 USA e-mail: (see http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html).}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{J. Doe and J. Doe are with Anonymous University.}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{Manuscript received April 19, 2005; revised August 26, 2015.}}
\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~14, No.~8, August~2015}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for IEEE Communications Society Journals}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Communications Society, IEEE, IEEEtran, journal, \LaTeX, paper, template.
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
\section{Introduction}
$I_E(0)$
\end{document}
```

PS: I have removed the unnecessary comments from the original file available at:
[IEEE Template](http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/Communications_Society_Win_or_Mac_LaTeX2e_journals_style_file.zip)

Comment: It doesn't compile because I don't have the package _newtxmath_. Could this package - even if you have it installed, which I assume - be the reason for strange behavior with math expressions?

Comment: @ubaabd Interestingly, I can reproduce your problem using `pdflatex` while your MWE works fine if I use `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally found a cure.

I opened the DVI file in DVI viewer shipped with Miktex 2.9, and it showed that it is installing some fonts. Once fonts were installed, I recompiled the file and got PDF output.

I'm not sure if it is the solution, but it worked.